# I am getting a InvalidDataContract exception in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I added a new DTO derived from an already existing DTO to my shared DTO assembly, added the new DTO as `KnownType` to the service implementation and as `ServiceKnownType` to the service interface.

However, when I am trying to update my client that reuses the DTO assembly, I get the following exception:

> Type 'MyNewDerivedTypeDto' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

However, *none* of my DTOs has the `DataContract` attribute applied and it works with all of the other DTOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the new DTO class doesn't have a default constructor. Each DTO to be used by the default WCF serializer needs to have a default constructor. Unfortunately, the exception in this case is pretty misleading.